# Is there a way to set up Xdebug on Windows without submitting that form with your phpinfo() dump?

Tags: windows, windows-10, php, setup, xdebug

On https://xdebug.org/docs/install , in the Windows section, it says:

> Follow these instructions to get Xdebug installed.

This leads to: https://xdebug.org/wizard , which only has a textfield and minimal instructions which state:

> Please paste the full output of phpinfo() and submit the form to receive tailored download and installation instructions.

The output of `phpinfo()` contains a wealth of personal information. I do not wish to submit any information. I merely wish to install Xdebug on Windows with my existing PHP 8.2. Is there some way to get the list of instructions without submitting this form with valid input data?

I have tried to submit it empty and with gibberish, but it wouldn't show me any information.

All I'm looking for is a simple list such as:

1. "Add this line to your php.ini: blablabla".
2. Etc., etc.
3. "Restart PHP to use Xdebug!"

I've tried but failed to get in touch with anyone responsible.

I have in fact got stuck at this step a number of times over the years, since I first heard of Xdebug. Now that I'm dealing with this again, I'm reminded of all the past times when this same thing happened, and I would love to be told something which I've just missed.

PS: The instructions for Linux seem to be unique for that OS, so I can't use those to help me set Xdebug up on Windows.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is a way to set up Xdebug on Windows without submitting the form with your phpinfo() dump. You can follow the steps below to install Xdebug on Windows:

1. Download the appropriate Xdebug DLL file for your version of PHP from the Xdebug website's download page (https://xdebug.org/download).
2. Copy the downloaded DLL file to your PHP extension directory (e.g. C:\php\ext).
3. Edit your php.ini file and add the following line to enable Xdebug:
   **zend_extension=""**
   Replace  with the full path to the Xdebug DLL file you copied in step 2.
4. Optionally, you can configure Xdebug settings in your php.ini file. For example, you can set the Xdebug remote debugging port:
   **xdebug.remote_port=**
   Replace  with a port number of your choice (e.g. 9000).
5. Restart your web server or PHP process to load the Xdebug extension.

After completing these steps, Xdebug should be installed and ready to use. You can verify that Xdebug is installed and enabled by running the **php -m** command in a terminal and checking for "Xdebug" in the list of loaded extensions.

Comment: Thanks. I wish they had hired you to make their website. Those instructions should be in place of the form, or above it. I don't understand why they made it the way they did.

Answer (score 0):

You should follow the instructions for Windows in the
Zen Help article
[Installing Xdebug](https://help.zend.com/zendstudio/current/content/installing_xdebug.htm).

This will point to the
[Xdebug Downloads page](http://xdebug.org/download)
where you may find downloads for
"PHP 8.2 VS16 (64 bit)" and for "PHP 8.2 VS16 TS (64 bit)".

Follow the instructions to finish the installation, then configure it for your software.

If using Zend, do
[configure Xdebug in Zend Studio](https://help.zend.com/zendstudio/current/content/configuring_xdebug.htm)
to begin debugging.

Comment: But I have nothing to do with Zend or Zend Studio?

Comment: You may then ignore this part. Answer modified.